# Creating validation for Pojo in servicemix

Tags: java, validation, apache-camel, pojo, apache-servicemix

I have a pojo with some annotations as below.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;


import java.util.Date;

@XmlRootElement()
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class Author {
@NotNull
private int contactId;

@Min(value = 1000000000000L, message = "EAN is less than 13 digits")
@Max(value = 9999999999999L, message = "EAN is greater than 13 digits")
@JsonProperty("EAN")
private long EAN;


@NotNull(message = "First name is compulsory")   
private String person_firstname;

@NotNull(message="Email Address is compulsory")     
@Pattern(regexp = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$", message = "Email Address is not a valid format")   
private String person_email;
// getters and setters
}
```

below is my validator calss.

```
public class AuthorValidator implements Processor {

public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    String exceptions="Exception Occured";
    try {           
    String jsonBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeReference<List<Author>> mapType = new TypeReference<List<Author>>() {};
    List<Author> authorList = objectMapper.readValue(jsonBody, mapType);

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();   

    for(Author au : authorList){

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Author>> violations = validator.validate(au);       
    for (ConstraintViolation<Author> violation : violations) {
        exceptions+=violation.getMessage(); 


    }
    }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        exceptions=e.getMessage();
    }
    exchange.getOut().setBody(exceptions);

}
```

when i test the class in eclipse it gives me a correct validation output. but when i am trying to call the from servicemix its throwing the below error.

```
Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could 
be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
```

i tried to install all the bundles but still error persists.
    Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: hibernate-validator : 5.0.2
    Hibernate Validator Engine
    camel-bean-validator
    Bean Validation API

Also all the required jars are in build path

can you please let me know what bundles i need to install on servicemix to make validation work.

Comment: Try install camel-bean-validator feature

Comment: thanks @ClausIbsen . I tried it but still facing getting the same exception
i have the below bundles installed already.
Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: aspectj
ClassMate
camel-bean-validator
Expression Language 2.2 Implementation
Hibernate Validator Engine

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented with the same in apache camel. Use the following link for the same.

[Running Hibernate Validator in the JBoss Fuse](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/734273?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001Css5AAC)

Answer (score 0):

Having the validator and jackson dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-bean-validator</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>         
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and the the annotated class:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

public class Author {

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private int contactId;
}
```

I would definitely use the unmarshall + bean-validator endpoint and forget about the unmarshall-validation Processor:

```
<unmarshal>
    <json library="Jackson"
            unmarshalTypeName="Author" />
</unmarshal>
<to uri="bean-validator://author" />
...
```